# Does making python more compact, make it more efficient?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, readability, redundancy

Ignoring code readability, is it worth removing redundant variables?

Eg. converting this code:

```
seconds = (milisec / 1000) % 60
minutes = milisec // (1000 * 60)
name = "{:>3}-{:0>5.2f}".format(minutes, seconds)
```

into:

```
name = "{:>3}-{:0>5.2f}".format(
    milisec // (1000 * 60), # minutes
    (milisec / 1000) % 60,  # seconds
    )
```

Comment: I hardly see any difference in both approaches. Approach 1 is just slightly more cleaner and that is it really,

Comment: "Ignoring code readability" - Or, and hear me out on this, how about we don't do that?

Comment: assigning to a variable is one bytecode instruction, and referencing it is another... so a very marginal, practically irrelevant difference. In this sort of code? Undoubtedly **not worth it.** If you are micro-optimizing at that level, CPython is likely the wrong tool.

Comment: Notice how the first form didn't require comments to tell you what it was doing?  That's the sign of better code.

Comment: Go for your first option - but for both options if `milisec` is supposed to be a count of milliseconds it should probably be `millisec`. Unless this code is going to be executed a gazillion times, I’m sure there are more important things to worry about in the design and implementation of your solution.

Comment: What does ***efficient*** python mean?  Execution time?  Memory use?  Stack use?  Programmer understandability (therefore development time efficiency)?  CPU register consumption?

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In term of execution time, the compact code is **slighlty** faster than the *long* code.
A quick evaluation could be this:

[image]

That being said, the readability of the code **matters**. It is one of the milestones of Python code. Debugging, maintenance, team working (just to name a few) take advantage of a better code readability.

Comment: It's worth noting that, even after 10 million iterations, the two approaches operate fall within or very near each other's standard deviation, meaning which one operates faster could very well depend on other aspects that are outside the programmer's control. Even ignoring that, the difference between the operations is in the order of _half a nanosecond._ This is the very definition of a micro-optimization that should *_never_* be prioritized over code readability.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your second piece of code, as you say more compact, will be slightly more efficient as assigning to variables correspond to some machine instructions.

```
from timeit import timeit

def function():

    milisec = 173000

    seconds = (milisec / 1000) % 60
    minutes = milisec // (1000 * 60)
    name = "{:>3}-{:0>5.2f}".format(minutes, seconds)


print(timeit(stmt='function()', setup='from __main__ import function', ))



def function2():
    milisec = 173000
    name = "{:>3}-{:0>5.2f}".format(
    milisec // (1000 * 60), # minutes
    (milisec / 1000) % 60,  # seconds
    )

print(timeit(stmt='function2()', setup='from __main__ import function2', ))
```

see some difference on one run of batches (in seconds)

[image]

Comment: This benchmark isn't only testing the relevant parts of code (e.g. `milisec = 173000` has nothing to do with the code being tested and should be pulled out) and doesn't include other relevant info to the benchmark for the results to be meaningful. For example, how many iterations of each function were run? What's the average runtime and standard deviation of each iteration? How many times was the benchmark run?

Comment: And to answer your question, you might think that instantiating the variable in both tests would equal out, but what you are testing for is an operational difference on the order of _billionths_ of a second or less. Assuming you can even find a practical difference at that scale, doing so requires you eliminating as many superfluous operations from your benchmark as possible. Arbitrary data points are noise, and noise skews results, then when your actual data is the same magnitude as your noise, you end up without any usable data. You don't need a "PhD" to understand basic statistics, dude.

Comment: You posted your results, and I said that the lack of transparency and rigor around how you produced and presented those results made your conclusion misleading and unreliable. You could've easily just tweaked your code and included the relevant information (which `timeit` provides by default) and it would've addressed every issue. Instead you decide to argue about this and claim that I am "bashing you". StackOverflow exists to provide quality answers. Your answer is not very good quality, and I told you precisely why. Why are you taking this so personally?

Comment: In other words, compare your answer to the top answer. They used the exact same approach you did, but they tested only the code that needed to be tested and presented their findings in a very transparent and professional way. The amount of effort it would take you to have the quality of your answer match theirs is minuscule. This is an incredibly silly thing to take umbridge over.

Comment: Yes you are right. I accept that you comment and correct my answer if you find it lacks some rigor. I just found your reaction a bit disproportioned, but it's only personal interpretation. Let's close it here. Always do more and more accurate is better than do less for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Creating variables take a little place in memory, so it would be faster if you don't do so. However, it is a really small difference.

Comment: There needs to be a huge label with blinking neon lights saying that while the creation and instantiation of a variable are, strictly speaking, less performant than an option which doesn't do that, the difference is entirely negligible to the point of being well within the margin of error on virtually any benchmarking system and is not even worth considering on all but the absolute most demanding of speed/memory efficiency requirements.